# Streaming pdf files using spark streaming filestream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am building an application that scans pdf files and extract data from them.

I have already built an application that does batch processing using spark core but now I want the data to be continuously streamed from the directory.

How can I use spark streaming filestream method to read pdf files from a directory?

And should this directory be an hdfs directory ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your sample code of your tried options! This is to understand your current api's which you are using and to advise you accordingly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i am using spark 1.6.2  i don't really see the need in posting my sample code because it is irrelevant of what i am asking about.

Comment: @fadyzohdy, did you find a solution for this? If so, can you please share the idea. I'm having similar requirement, but for ORC file though.